# How do I add a mesh to a face which is 45 degrees to either the X or Y axis?

Tags: objects

I want to add 2 separate mesh cubes to each face of an octagon to represent a window and panel beneath the window. I considered adding the meshes to one face of the octagon, selecting the octagon and two new meshes and rotating all 45 degrees on the Z axis and then adding 2 more mesh cubes and rotate again until all 8 sides have been 'populated' with the two mesh cubes.
Is there an easier method such as selecting all 8 faces of the octagon and then adding the 2 new meshes which populates every face?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best for this kind of object is probably to work with an *Array* modifier:

Create your octagonal cylinder, only keep one face, create an empty at the same location as the origin of the cylinder:

[image]

Give your cylinder an *Array* modifier, *Count > 8*, enable *Object Offset*, choose the empty as *Object*, rotate the empty 45° on Z:

[image]

Now whatever you'll do on your object will be replicated x8:

[image]

Comment: John, you should consider accepting an answer, or if you've another issue please ask in the comments part of the answer(s).

Comment: How do I accept both answers as they both have their merits and I could use either? I also did ask a further question (below).

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @moonboots is probably the best to do it like that right from the start. Another possible way when you already have the octagon and two cubes representing the window and panel:

1. Switch the *Transform Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor*. In your example file this enough, because the origin (and center) of the octagon as well as the cursor are at the world's center. If the octagon is placed somewhere else, select it, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*.

   [image: change pivot point]
2. Select both cubes which you want to place around the octagon and go into top view by pressing <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>.

   Duplicate them as "linked duplicates" by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (instead of normal duplicates with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

   Do not yet confirm the duplication but instead press <kbd>R</kbd> to start rotating the duplicate and enter <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to rotate by 45°, then confirm the action with <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>.

   [image: linked duplicate and rotate]
3. Since you did the duplication and rotation in a single action, you can now simply repeat it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> 6 times until you have the cubes on all 8 sides.

   [image: repeat last action]
4. Because you have made linked duplicates of the cubes, you can now change their meshes in *Edit Mode* and the changes will be applied to all duplicates as well since they share the same object data.

   [image: shared object data]

   And this also applies for changing the materials on one of the duplicates, the others will get the same materials too.

   [image: shared material data]

Comment: Thanks moonboots and Gordon. Both solutions are great. I think I will go with Gordon's solution but may start again as my octagon is 'indeveloped' and so I could start again. Maybe I will try each one for the exercises and to learn more.  I had NO idea that an array could be used as I tried but didn't know about " enable Object Offset, choose the empty as Object". BTW I think it is time I contributed financially here.

Comment: @JohnArnold You should definitely try moonboots' solution as well, even if only for exercise, because with the _Object Offset_ you can really do interesting things. An empty is always good as the target object since it will not be rendered, but you can use others as well. The great thing is, it is not only the rotation per count which can be set by this, also the translation and scale, for example to have the duplicates getting smaller or larger per step.

Comment: @JohnArnold And it does not matter if you transform the target object (the empty) or the arrayed object or both, the offset per count will always be calculated as _(target object - arrayed object)_ for location and rotation and _(target object / arrayed object)_ for scaling.

Comment: Hey guys.   I have just found some time to try these solutions but how do I create an 'empty'? Start with a cube and scale it down to nothing?

Comment: @JohnArnold An Empty is not a mesh object like a cube. In the _Add_ menu which you get with Shift+A you have a lot of different object types like _Mesh_, _Curve_, _Camera_, _Light_ etc., and one of these object types is _Empty_, with different shapes. For example _Plain Axes_, _Sphere_, _Cube_ and more but the shape is just the visual appearance to indicate where the empty is, it has no effect on  the array method or anything, it has no mesh or geometry of any kind - it is "empty" and only holds location, rotation and scale information in a point in space. It does not get rendered either.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I see it.

Comment: I had no problem using your method on a simple 8 sided cylinder HOWEVER I can't work out how to add 2 other mesh 'cubes' to each face of the octagon. I tried adding them BEFORE applying the array modifier by selecting all meshes on the single face but that didn't work. I thought perhaps that if I add the extra meshes to one face of the octagon and it would automatically 'replicate' on  the other 7 faces but no that doesn't work. Is the only method to JOIN the three meshes into one before applying the array?

Comment: @JohnArnold I'm sorry but this site is not for longer discussions. Better place a new question. And I'm not quite sure if I correctly understand how you are doing it, to me it seems as if there is a profound misunderstanding of how the _Array_ modifier works... or joining objects that hold modifiers... and why would you want to apply a modifier if you still want to edit it? Anyway, we cannot discuss all that here in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I have started a new thread as although  I now understand about adding extra mesh cubes BEFORE adding the array modifier I don't know how to set EXACT dimensions in edit mode and scale is difficult.

Comment: @JohnArnold That's why I suggested asking a new question, because adding meshes with exact dimensions has nothing to do with using the _Array_ modifier, but when I talked about the misunderstanding I meant, if you think you have to add extra cubes before _adding_ a modifier then you are wrong. But you said _apply_ the modifier which in Blender terminology means converting the modified mesh into real permanent geometry and removing the modifier. So you definitely can add cubes after _adding_ the modifier, but if you want them to be arrayed you need to do that before _applying_ the modifier.

Comment: Yes a comment some time later but just to advise I had need to add a post complete with light fitting at each of the 4 corners of a (new) octagonal deck and used your method which worked brilliantly. I also needed to add a metal framed glass balustrade to the 8 sides of the same octagon deck and your method once again was a 'breeze' to use. Thanks again.