# How to add extra meshes to an octagon created with the array modifier

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

In a previous question ([How do I add a mesh to a face which is 45 degrees to either the X or Y axis?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292075/how-do-i-add-a-mesh-to-a-face-which-is-45-degrees-to-either-the-x-or-y-axis)) one of the methods suggested was using the array modifier and an 'empty' which I am able to replicate. However when I add extra meshes to one face of my object it doesn't replicate it on all the other faces.
What I did was add a cylinder with 8 vertices. I then removed all but one of the faces of the octagon (I did this in edit mode selecting edges and deleted those edges). I then added an 'empty' at the origin of the initial octagon, added an array modifier to the now single face with a count of 8 and object offset selected and the object selection set to the empty. I then rotated the empty on the z axis 45 degrees and my octagon was draw as expected.
I now am trying to add two mesh cubes to all faces. I add them to one face and expect that to be replicated to the other 7 faces but it doesn't. I have tried adding before 'applying' the array modifier and after and it still will not work.
[image]

Comment: You need to add the cubes in Edit mode, not in Object mode

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cubes to be part of your octagonal object, you need to add them in *Edit* mode, not in *Object* mode.

Comment: Thanks moonboots. I have often seen meshes added in edit mode and always wondered what is the 'criteria' for when to add meshes in edit mode and when to add them in object mode. I have always used object mode before.    Also how do I change dimensions by axis? When adding a mesh cube I can only find resizing the entire cube not say on the Z axis?

Comment: From an extensive internet search it seems that dimensions CANNOT be set in edit mode.  So is the only method of changing dimensions (in edit mode) via the scale 'tool' and so just a case of 'fiddling'  to get the size close to the ideal?

Comment: If you add a cube in Edit mode and want to change its size, just use the scale tool (S). What you can't do in Edit mode is applying the scale. As for creating a mesh in Edit mode or creating a new object in Object mode, it really depends on the situation, generally you create a new object if it's considered as an object in real life, and put all its pieces within this object, but you may have reasons why you want to keep the pieces as separate objects, for example you may prefer your robot to have separate pieces.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that I could get around this by adding the extra mesh cubes in object mode and then selecting all and Join into a single mesh but could not get the array modifier to work correctly (to create the octagon). Pity. Maybe I should 'resort' to the other method suggested as I really prefer to add a window to all 8 sides (it's a pretend lighthouse) which has a frame and glass using 'bridge edge loops' to create the frame.

Comment: @JohnArnold If you are not able to create the extra objects in _Edit Mode_, you can do it in _Object Mode_ and join them. When you join objects with Ctrl+J and they have modifiers on them, only the modifiers of the _active_ object (that's the one with lighter orange, the others are darker orange) are kept, the others are lost. Also the joined object will get the origin of the _active_ object. So you can add a cube in object mode, scale it to your liking etc. and then join it with the object that has the _Array_ modifier. But this one has to be the _active_ object.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That works really well.