# MIrroring a Hexagon (other than 90°

Tags: mirror

I'm a total newbie, and I'm tring around right now with some modeling.

My plan is to do a hollow Hexagon and to cut holes in the 6 sides.
Is there a way to mirror it?
I only find the "normal" mirror for the 3 axis with 90°.
For the HExagon i neet other angles.

Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad english.

Happy

Comment: Maybe use an Array modifier with an empty as object offset instead of a mirror?

Comment: See my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292075/how-do-i-add-a-mesh-to-a-face-which-is-45-degrees-to-either-the-x-or-y-axis

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the Array (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/292075/how-do-i-add-a-mesh-to-a-face-which-is-45-degrees-to-either-the-x-or-y-axis)